# mysqli select query error 1064

Tags: php, mysqli

*trying to make a query:*

```
$word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($words[$value]);
$valor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'w_id' FROM '$valor' WHERE word='$word'");
```

**But**
the result is :

> Error (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''eng' WHERE word='msms'' at line 1

here `eng` is a value of `$valor`

I tried allready a lot of possibilities to insert the variable, and changed names of tables, but nothing helps

tried `'".$valor."'` as well

Comment: Do not quote column and table names, lest they be treated as string literals.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: Show us the resultant query

Comment: I advise you _not_ to use an input value in `$valor` as a table name there anyway, since `real_escape_string()` cannot correctly protect that against SQL injection.   Instead, if you need to dynamically supply a table name you should check the value against an array of acceptable possible values.

Comment: Use backticks around your table name, not quotes.

Comment: Why do you have table name in a variable?

Comment: thanx  Michael Berkowski, that was the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Do not put quotation marks around the table/field names:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT w_id FROM " . $valor . " WHERE word = '" . $word . "'");
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes it is.

Comment: You should take back your `-1` and I quote you: *"Unfortunately, this site is not about fixing your code."* as per [your comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572191/pdo-if-fetch-then-print-rsmt-fetchpdofetch-obj-wont-show-any-result#comment30771717_20572191) Josh merely outlined where the error was. @YourCommonSense

Comment: Haha! I can't believe I got -1'ed - @YourCommonSense would you rather I re-wrote his whole DB integration as well? I'm not in the business of fixing someone's bad practice, merely pointing out how to get it going.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the error was merely outlined in the *comments*. While he offered a *solution*. A wrong one. Nobody asked him to, but as he volunteered and failed, he got deserved -1.

Comment: Then (theoretically), the OP should also get `-1` if you're going to start doing that. @YourCommonSense